# How to make independent select all checkbox to display table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I want to make few checkboxes along with **"Select all"** checkbox. The functionality is as follows:

1. Select checkbox/es to display table column/s.     Uncheck
   checkbox/es to hide table column/s - (toggle)
2. Select "Select all" checkbox to display all columns of tables.
   Uncheck "Select all" checkbox to hide all columns of tables -
   (toggle).
3. If "Select all" checkbox is marked, then any previously marked
   the checkbox should not be shown checked.
4. No effect is made on table columns if any other checkbox is checked,
   if     "Select all" checkbox is checked.

```js
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Check Box</title>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="all" checked> Select All</p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="symbol" checked> symbol</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="priceChange" checked> priceChange</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="priceChangePercent" checked> priceChangePercent</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="weightedAvgPrice" checked> weightedAvgPrice</p>
    
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
 <thead> 
 <tr> 
     <th  class="symbol all">symbol</th>
     <th class="priceChange all">priceChange</th>
     <th class="priceChangePercent all">priceChangePercent</th> 
     <th class="weightedAvgPrice all">weightedAvgPrice</th>  
 </tr> 
 </thead>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  $("all").click(function () {
     $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your jquery functions a bit. Instead of toggle, I am using show or hide column, depending upon checkbox's checked property. And when select all is checked, I am disabling all other check boxes.

```
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="all" checked> Select All</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="symbol" checked> symbol</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="priceChange" checked> priceChange</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="priceChangePercent" checked> priceChangePercent</p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="weightedAvgPrice" checked> weightedAvgPrice</p>

        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="1" width="100%"> 
            <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th class="symbol all">symbol</th>
                <th class="priceChange all">priceChange</th>
                <th class="priceChangePercent all">priceChangePercent</th> 
                <th class="weightedAvgPrice all">weightedAvgPrice</th>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td class="symbol all">sddsasdaasd</td>
                <td class="priceChange all">iuuiuyui</td>
                <td class="priceChangePercent all">nbnbnmmnmn</td>
                <td class="weightedAvgPrice all">fdsgfgfddfg</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>



       <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
                    //console.log($(this).attr("name"));
                    //console.log($(this).prop('checked'));

                    if($(this).attr("name") === "all") {
                        var chkAll = $("input:checkbox[name='all']");

                        if( chkAll.is(":checked")){
                            $(":checkbox").not(chkAll).prop("checked",false);//THIS IS IMPORTANT
                            $(":checkbox").not(chkAll).attr("disabled", true);

                        }
                        else {
                            $(":checkbox").not(chkAll).prop("checked",false);//THIS IS IMPORTANT   
                            $(":checkbox").not(chkAll).attr("disabled", false);
                        }                           

                    }

                    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
                    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        $(column).show();    
                    }
                    else {
                        $(column).hide();    
                    }

                });                    

            });

        </script>
```